Do left singular vectors change after multiplication from the right
Let $M=U\Sigma V^\top$ be a compact SVD of a real matrix and let $W$ be a matrix such that $W^\top W = I$. Can we claim that $U$ are left singular vectors of $MW$? I though that the answer is no because we do not know if $W W^\top=I$ to claim that $V^\top WW^\top V=I$, but I'm not entirely sure if this is correct.

The answer is YES! because you would implicitely have meant $W$ is square since, otherwise, the size of the matrix would be changed when multiplied by $W$. For if $W$ is square, $WW^T=W^TW=I$!
@John Smith does this make sense?

Thank you. In my case $W$ is not a square matrix and I work with compact SVD. It has dimensions $pxq$ with $p>q$.

yes, then the answer is NO. Obviously, if it were multiplied from the left, the answer would be YES. Can I ask where this problem pops up? I mean I may be helpful if I understand the context around this question!

Thank you, this comes from the proof of Theorem 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02724. Equation (32) implicitly assumes that $U_1$ are are left-singular vectors of $X_1^{(t)}=X_1W^{(t)}$ with some rectangular $W^{(t)}$ appearing on the previous page. We know that $X_1$ has left singular vectors $U_1$, but we do not know much about $X_1W^{(t)}$.
